# Move selection based on input for X, Y, and Z axes

Tags: python, python-2.x, maya

My first use of classes with Python. Very simple code which I feel may be further simplified. Please break my code or give me input on where it could have been better/efficient.

```
import maya.cmds as mc
from functools import partial

class MoveSelTool(object):
    '''Tool for moving selected object or objects by a 
    value specified by user on the X, Y, and Z axis.'''

    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass       
    if(mc.window("ak_move_sel_tool_window", query=True, exists=True)):
        mc.deleteUI("ak_move_sel_tool_window")

    def build_window_UI(self):
        '''Builds the window for GUI''' 

        self.window = mc.window("ak_move_sel_tool_window", 
                                title="Move Selection Tool")
        self.columnLayout = mc.columnLayout()
        self.txt_directions = mc.text(align="left", 
                                    label="Directions: Input translation increment.\n")
        self.rowColumn = mc.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=8)
        self.txt_x = mc.text(label=" X: ", 
                            align="right")         
        self.txtfld_x = mc.textField("mst_txtfld_x_value",
                                    text="0", 
                                    ann='input units to move X', 
                                    width=50)
        self.txt_y = mc.text(label=" Y: ", 
                            align="right")         
        self.txtfld_y = mc.textField("mst_txtfld_y_value",
                                    text="0",  
                                    ann='input units to move Y', 
                                    width=50)
        self.txt_z = mc.text(label=" Z: ", 
                            align="right")         
        self.txtfld_z = mc.textField("mst_txtfld_z_value",
                                    text="0",  
                                    ann='input units to move Z', 
                                    width=50)
        self.txt_space = mc.text(label="  ")    
        self.move_btn = mc.button(label="Move") 

        #ui commands
        mc.button(self.move_btn, 
                edit=True, 
                command=partial(self.move_selection))
        mc.textField("mst_txtfld_x_value",
                    edit=True, 
                    enterCommand=partial(self.move_selection))
        mc.textField("mst_txtfld_y_value",
                    edit=True, 
                    enterCommand=partial(self.move_selection))             
        mc.textField("mst_txtfld_z_value",
                    edit=True, 
                    enterCommand=partial(self.move_selection))

        #show ui
        mc.showWindow(self.window)

    def query_mst_user_input(self):
        '''Queries all 3 textfields and returns 
        values of X, Y, and Z in a single list'''

        self.x_value = mc.textField("mst_txtfld_x_value", 
                                    query=True,
                                    text=True)

        self.y_value = mc.textField("mst_txtfld_y_value", 
                                    query=True,
                                    text=True)

        self.z_value = mc.textField("mst_txtfld_z_value", 
                                    query=True,
                                    text=True)

        return (self.x_value, self.y_value, self.z_value) 

    def move_selection(self, *args):
        '''Convert input or lack thereof into floats 
        and plug them into Maya's move command'''

        self.mst_user_selection = mc.ls(selection=True)    
        self.mst_user_inputs = self.query_mst_user_input()
        user_x = self.mst_user_inputs[0]
        user_y = self.mst_user_inputs[1]
        user_z = self.mst_user_inputs[2]
        print len(user_x)
        if len(user_x) == 0:
            user_x = 0
        if len(user_y) == 0:
            user_y = 0
        if len(user_z) == 0:
            user_z = 0            
        print "Your X is {0}".format(float(user_x))
        print "Your Y is {0}".format(float(user_y))
        print "Your Z is {0}".format(float(user_z))
        mc.move(float(user_x), 
                float(user_y), 
                float(user_z),
                self.mst_user_selection, 
                relative=True)
    def show(self):
        '''Display UI'''
        self.build_window_UI()
mst=MoveSelTool()
mst.show()
```

Comment: Indentation of "if(mc.window..." seems a bit awkward...

Answer (score 1):

Alright, your code looks around but it could be improved slightly:

---

In the lines

> ```
> def __init__(self, *args):
>     pass       
> if(mc.window("ak_move_sel_tool_window", query=True, exists=True)):
> ```

You should add whitespace between the two lines, and also between `if` and `(`.

---

PEP8, Python's official style guide suggests naming your variables like this `x_value`, rather than `self.txtfld_y`, and also using `text_field_y` rather than an abbreviation.

---

I would suggest turning:

> ```
>     user_x = self.mst_user_inputs[0]
>     user_y = self.mst_user_inputs[1]
>     user_z = self.mst_user_inputs[2]
>     print len(user_x)
>     if len(user_x) == 0:
>         user_x = 0
>     if len(user_y) == 0:
>         user_y = 0
>     if len(user_z) == 0:
>         user_z = 0
> ```

into an array.

---

I would suggest turning `ann='input units to move X'` into a string elsewhere like:  `string_elsewhere = 'input units to move ' ... ann = string_elsewhere + 'X'`

Comment: Can you give a reason for your suggestions? why should i turn those lines into an array?  also, why should ann be put into a variable? does it make much of a difference?